# Cannot submit a form on SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am fairly new to SpringMVC and have a form that can not submit to the back-end. I created the form as following and when I submit it error 404 will be returned. I changed action to /MyProject/contact but did not work.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
                action="/contact">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputName2">Name 
                        </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                            name="name" placeholder="Your name" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputName2">Email
                            Address</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                            name="email" placeholder="Your email" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputName2">Phone
                            Number</label> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone"
                            name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputName2">Enquiry</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"
                            placeholder="Please enter your enquiry"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2 " style="float: right;">
                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"
                            class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(Contact contact, Model model){
        System.err.println("Contact Name is:" + contact.getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /contact

type Status report

message /contact

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: Try to Remove The slash in Front of Contact, because maybe the context path is missing.

Comment: which contact? front-end,back-end or both?

Comment: He is talking about contact in form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by help of [minion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068231/cannot-submit-a-form-on-springmvc/29068385#29068385), following [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/) and adding following link

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView contactForm() {
        System.err.println("here in GET");
        return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its beacuse spring does not know how to pass the param **Contact contact** to your controller method. You need to do couple of things to make it work. Change your form to like below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" modelAttribute="contact" action="/contact">
```

Your controller to take contact as model attribute.

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, Model model){
        System.err.println("Contact Name is:" + contact.getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

For a better understanding of what a model attribute does, there are plenty of samples and explanation online. Hope this helps.